# Set and get method not working

Tags: java, get, set

I have a `public static void` method which reads information from some source. Then I use those set methods to save those information. The get/set methods are declared in some separate `public` classes. The get method works fine within the class where I've defined also the set method, but it doesn't work in any other class/method. I get just the value `null`. I don't know why... Could anyone help me?

```
public static void InformationFinder() {
        String identificationID = null;     
        String flag = null;     
        String nickname = null;

        // part to read the informations (saved in the variables above)

       UserInfo user = new UserInfo();

       user.setIdentificationID(identificationID);
       user.setVorname(flag);   
       user.setNachname(nickname);

       // shows me up the correct ID    
       System.out.println("Tell me the ID: " + user.getIdentificationID());
}



public class UserInfo {

    public String identificationID;
    public String flag;
    public String nickname;

    public UserInfo () {

    public String getIdentificationID() {
        return Nachname;        
    }

    public String getFlag() {
        return flag;
    }

    public String getNickname() {
        return nickname;
    }


    // set Methoden 

    public void setIdentificationID(String identID) {
        this.identificationID = identID;        
    }

    public void setFlag(String flag) {
        this.flag= flag;        
    }

    public void setNickname (String nickname) {
        this.nickname = nickname;       
    }
}




 public static void main(String[] args) {

        UserInfo user = new UserInfo();          

        // shows me only null as result
        System.out.println(UserInfo.getIdentificationID());
 }
```

I know that maybe the problem is because of a second instantiating of the object. But I found no other way to use the get Method in the 'main()' function.

Comment: Did you try debug your code?

Comment: Set a breakpoint and step through your code. Consider making the fields in the UserInfo class private, because you're exposing getters/setters anyway.

Comment: you get null because the value is really `null` ! .

Comment: you haven't set any value to user object. I have add a solution in my post below. Try this and let me know.

Comment: might want to call InformationFinder() in main but not sure why SO code template treats it as a class name.

Comment: and you definitely need to learn oop (which is java based on)

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem is in the following portion of your code (in your main() method ) -

```
 UserInfo user = new UserInfo();          

 // shows me only null as result
 System.out.println(UserInfo.getIdentificationID());
```

In the above code in main method you are creating a new `UserInfo()` . But the set method is not applied for the `user` created here. This method is applied for other object. Use set method for the same object.

The `UserInfo` object you have created in - `public static void InformationFinder()` function is diffrent from the `UserInfo` object created in `main()` method. As you set some `user` property in `InformationFinder()` method like -

```
user.setIdentificationID(identificationID);
user.setVorname(flag);   
user.setNachname(nickname);
```

In main() method you also have to add these setter method -

```
user.setIdentificationID(identificationID);
user.setVorname(flag);   
user.setNachname(nickname);
```

Hope it will help.
Thanks a lot.

Comment: Thanks for ur solution, but i dont have the information of identificationID, flag and nickname not in the main() method.

Comment: well many answers could solve the problem, calling the InformationFinder function in main for instance but hey then the OP won't learn

Comment: So from somewhere you have to provide it or use dummy information. Other wise there is no way to get rid of the null. Because user in `main()` method is completely different from the user in `informatinFinder()` method.

Comment: Okay, for the main() function could work, but what is when i want another method in a another class which writes the information in a database. There i have definitly not access to the identificationID, flag and nickname. I hope u know what i mean.

Comment: @Panther then use it in main(the code you posted doesn't seem to have any scanner, only null values)

Comment: @Panther from getting data from scanner you may create 'UserInfo` object with constructor. In this case no setter method will required too.

Comment: Maybe I have to explain again. I have the InformationFinder Method to get the information from the user. Now the aim was it to save those information, that i can use it in another class/method to write it a database. I want 2 seperate method's but i don't know how can the Database Method (which i want to add later)  the informations from the InformationFinder method.